# Google Apps Class to JList

Tags: java, swing, google-api, jlist

I am trying to display a load of groups in a JList for the user to select. I gather all the groups from the account and then I want to return them in a format to put into a model to display in a JList.

Would it be better to:

- Use only what information I need to display (name and id) and then just get the single group again from the server using this data when the user makes a selection; or
- Store each group in an object and create a toString() method so that when the user selects the item the user can call methods on the returned object right away without having to fetch the object.

There shouldn't be too many groups to get but if this method is used again for, lets say, users it may be a lot more.

I can see pro's and con's for both but I'm curious about what everyone else thinks and what method would be used. If there is a better way too I'm all ears

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what's is better here. I would determine an interface here.

```
public interface Group {
  long getId();
  String getName();
}
```

And use this interface in your list. So you can use both approaches, and if you need it - switch at runtime. In this case the dependend component should be prepared that it can get both variants of Group - basic and full.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a whirl. Still interested to see if other people mention any other ways too